# Table Adapter Configuration Wizard failing to configure tableadapter for mysql stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, web-config, dataset, tableadapter

I am attempting to create a TableAdapter in a dataset using the configuration wizard on a c# MVC application set to dot net 4.6.1. I am currently using visual studio 2015 update 3.
 The challenge I have is while trying to use MySQL when I try to add a stored procedure using the existing option or with the query builder it fails with

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

and when I try to use preview it fails with

> "Value cannot be null, Parameter name : adapter"

which is why I think it fails to create my table adapter. My stored procedure does not have a parameter. My set up is as follows

```
MySQL Server : 5.7.21
Connector Net: 6.10.7
MySQL for Visual Studio : 1.2.8
```

On Visual Studio I used the NuGet package manager to install 
`MySQL.Data
 MySQL.Data.Entity
 MySQL.Web` 
all @ version 6.10.7. I have found similar posts regarding this problem for previous versions of MySQL, However, the version which seems to work 6.9.9 does not have a NuGet package to install with and I had a mismatch error on my entity data model when I tried to use it. 
So far 6.10.7 has been the only version I can safely install with my EF model and my server explorer working. The only issue I have is using Dataset designer. 
The fixes that suggest I update my web.config file with

> AllowUserVariables=True;CheckParameters=False

have not helped. I have seen multiple other questions asked and tried some of the fixes however none have worked so far. 
My question is how do I debug an issue with the table adapter wizard failing?